# How to move file/folder to an already existing folder

Tags: c#

I'm working on something like recycle bin, that I need to move folder/files to already existing folder, I tried to use

```
Directory.Move
```

but it creates new directory and that's wrong for me, I have a specific directory to move to.
Can you help me?

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It seems do don't actually want to move the folder, you want to move the *contents* of the folder. If you want to do that, you have to tell the computer to do that:

```
void MoveContentsOfDirectory(string source, string target)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source))
    {
        var dest = Path.Combine(target, Path.GetFileName(file));
        File.Move(file, dest);
    }

    foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(source))
    {
        var dest = Path.Combine(target, Path.GetFileName(dir));
        Directory.Move(dir, dest);
    }

    // optional
    Directory.Delete(source);
}
```